# Is it possible to force evaluation of the macro in c?

Tags: c, macros, evaluation

This is working, but it's kinda heavy-footed solution

```cpp
#define COUNT_BITS_4b(Val) \
   ((Val) & 0x1) + (((Val) >> 1) & 0x1) + (((Val) >> 2) & 0x1) + (((Val) >> 3) & 0x1)
#define COUNT_BITS_8b(Val) \
   (COUNT_BITS_4b(Val) + COUNT_BITS_4b(Val >> 4))
#define COUNT_BITS_16b(Val) \
   (COUNT_BITS_8b(Val) + COUNT_BITS_8b(Val >> 8))
#define COUNT_BITS_32b(Val) \
   (COUNT_BITS_16b(Val) + COUNT_BITS_16b(Val >> 16))
#define COUNT_BITS_32b(Val) \
   (COUNT_BITS_16b(Val) + COUNT_BITS_16b((Val >> 31) >> 1))
....
```

I would like to get rid of this part, (replace it with something like this `#define ULONG_BIT` **Eval(**`(COUNT_BITS(ULONG_MAX))`**)**

```cpp
#if COUNT_BITS_128b(ULONG_MAX) == 32
   #define ULONG_BIT 32
#elif COUNT_BITS_128b(ULONG_MAX) == 33
   #define ULONG_BIT 33
#elif COUNT_BITS_128b(ULONG_MAX) == 34
   #define ULONG_BIT 34
....
#elif COUNT_BITS_128b(ULONG_MAX) == 128
   #define ULONG_BIT 128
#endif
```

Thx for any answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Macros aren't "evaluated" at all.  The preprocessor simply performs text substitution.

Comment: Won't `#define ULONG_BIT COUNT_BITS_128b(ULONG_MAX)` be enough? It is a (very complex, but still) *constant expression*, which any optimizing compiler would transform to a simple constant.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Will i not hit any macro size limit or something when i use ULONG_BIT defined as COUNT_BITS_128b(ULONG_MAX) in whole application ?

Comment: @Adam Mihalcin What about #if #else statements, they have to be evaluated during compilation time.

Comment: Oki i expanded `COUNT_BITS` macro to 4096 bits and used it couple of times. Looks like it will take a few minutes/hours to compile.

Comment: @Neko, really long macros *may* slow down your compilation substantially. I have seen that for clang 2.8, e.g.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but what do you want to achieve with these macros?  Are you just after the size of an unsigned long? Or is the macro for wider use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are really looking for a way that this resolves to a decimal value at preprocessing time something like this could do the trick:

```
#define NEKO_4294967295 32
... for all the values up to 128 ...
... for all possible variants with U or UL appended ...
#define NEKO_TESTER(VAL) NEKO_ ## VAL
#define ULONG_BITS NEKO_TESTER(ULONG_MAX)
```

Although technically it is not guaranteed that `ULONG_MAX` resolves to a simple decimal constant.

Comment: I like the idea, but like you said standard doesn't explicitly say that `ULONG_MAX` have to be defined as decadic number, so basically i will have to cover all possibilities (octal and hexadecimal as well) if i want to use it. Still nice idea.